# iOS SDK: UITableView Styling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, sdk

I've searched high a low for a solution to this problem. I can't find why the style from my nib isn't loading? If I change anything in the nibs the functioning stops. So I've resorted to overriding the style.

I have:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)inCoder
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is on the second view controller, so following from rootviewcontroller. I would rather fix it another way, but if I have to override it I can.

So, the table is now grouped, but how can I programatically change the view background colour?

Any help appreciated.

Ps. For the initial problem, I have 3 nibs: MainWindow.xib, RootViewController.xib and CollectionsViewController.xib created by following this tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews#Setting_up_the_Data_in_the_Root_View_Controller

The first table is styled using the RootViewController.xib, but changing CollectionsViewController.xib does nothing.

Cheers,
Rhys

EDIT:
Got it with:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.2 blue:0.5 alpha:0.7];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you override initWithCoder: method, you must call it's super version, which one is responsible for decoding the nib file data

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color of the Table view you need to redesign the table.
In your header viewcontroller add the following code and on IB connect the IBOutlet:

```
@interface TableController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {

    UITableView *tableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

and in your implementation file add on `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    CGFloat tableBorderLeft = 25;
    CGFloat tableBorderRight = 15;
    CGFloat tableBorderUP = 10;

    CGRect tableRect = self.view.frame;
    tableRect.origin.x += tableBorderLeft; // make the table begin a few pixels right from its origin
    tableRect.origin.y += tableBorderUP;
    tableRect.size.width -= tableBorderLeft + tableBorderRight; // reduce the width of the table
    tableView.frame = tableRect;

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];    
    tableView.opaque = NO;
    tableView.backgroundView = nil; 

    [super viewDidLoad];        
}
```

Hope that works for you

Comment: That didn't work I'm afraid. It stopped it from working. Is there a way to force it to style using the nib file? Cheers, Rhys.

Comment: init your tableView whitNibFile and add the code to viewdidload.
In IB you can't change background color.
unless you add the table as a subview to a viewcontroller (I guess)